# Can't turn off validation in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: jboss, openshift, jboss-developer-studio

I am brand new to JBoss Developer Studio and can't seem to get past something that seems as though it would be simple. I am building the front end of my Web application using Sencha ExtJS 6.0. This framework contains hundreds of client side files that I don't need validated.

However, no matter what I have tried I cannot turn off the validation process that occurs before a build. Developer Studio always starts validating these files and eventually runs out of memory. Here is what I have tried:

I have selected `Project -> Properties -> Validation` and un-selected every single validator. When I click Apply or OK it starts validating. I cancel the validation process and in a few seconds it starts validating again.

Another thing I tried was going into `Window -> Preferences -> Validation` and un-selected all validators. This didn't change anything either. I basically cannot work with my project now because Developer Studio starts validating on its own and eventually runs out of memory.

Like I said, I'm new to Developer Studio so I'm sure there is something basic that I'm missing here. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I am using JBoss Developer Studio 9.0.0.0GA.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Did you suspend manual or build validators, or both? Did you notice the 'Suspend all validators' option under validators? What validation error are you getting?

Comment: Not sure how my question could be any clearer.  When I selected Project-->Properties-->Validation I unchecked ALL of the validators, both manual and build. And yes I tried the 'Suspend all validators' option and it didn't stop the validation process either.

Comment: Sounds like a bug of some sort.